# How to set multi line XAxis values in Combined Chart (MPAndroidChart)?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, x-axis

How to set multi line XAxis values in Combined Chart with StackChart (MPAndroidChart) ??

XAxisRenderer is not working on Combined Chart with StackChart

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.